# Customized spring batch Item Flat Writer

Tags: spring-batch

I have a working spring batch program that creates a flat file , but I want to be able to put labels to my fields.

Here is my Pojo example Student

```
public class Student{

private String studentName;
private double gpa;


public String getStudentName() {
    return studentName;
}

public void setStudentName(String studentName) {
    this.studentName = studentName;
}

public double getGpa() {
    return dob;
}

public void setGpa(double gpa) {
    this.gpa= gpa;
}
```

Here is my rowmapper

```
public class StudentRowMapper implements RowMapper<Student>{

@Override
public Student mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {

    Student student= new Student();
    student.setStudentName(rs.getString("student_name"));
    student.setGpa(rs.getDouble("gpa"));

    return student;
}
```

}

Here is an extract of my XML file:

```
    <property name="lineAggregator">

        <!-- An Aggregator which converts an object into delimited list of strings -->
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineAggregator">

            <property name="delimiter" value="|" />

            <property name="fieldExtractor">


                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.BeanWrapperFieldExtractor">
                    <property name="names" value="studentName, gpa" />
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

It produces the following output

```
Rita Paul|3.8|
Han Yanagata|3.0|
```

I want to be able to put coustme prefix to every field, I want to be able to write a flat file that says

```
name=Rita Paul|gpa=3.8|
name=Han Yanagata|gpa=3.0|
```

Comment: Write a custom `LineAggregator`, it's pretty easy.

Answer (score 0):

In your row mapper you can customize by

```
public class StudentRowMapper implements RowMapper<Student>{

@Override
public Student mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {

    Student student= new Student();
    student.setStudentName("name="+rs.getString("student_name"));
    student.setGpa("gpa="+rs.getDouble("gpa"));

    return student;
}
```

Comment: GPA is a double you can't just Add "GPA="

Comment: anyway you are going to write it into file.so all of the member variables of Student you can take as String Variables

Comment: The problem with that I feel is that if later I want to apply business logic and let's say add an item processor to filter out GPAs lower than 3.0 I won't be able to

Comment: OK. then add it in processor level after your processing is completed. Or else you can write your own FlatFilewriter or else as  Luca Basso Ricci said you can write your own custom line aggregator.